# AS3 - ExternalInterface.addCallback, Access of undefined property

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to use javascript to run AS3 functions.  When I attempt to compile I'm getting an "Access of undefined property" error message.

I've read a few things online about this but I'm still not understanding it.  I want to have the flash file always listening for javascript.

Here is my AS3 code:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("song4", PauseMusicExt);
```

And my Javascript & HTML:

```
 function returnVar3(song3) { return this[song3]; }
  <input type="submit" name="playButton" id="playButton" value="Submit" onClick="returnVar('song3')"/>
```

Edit:  Here is the pauseMusic function:

```
function pauseMusicExt():void
    {
        songPosition = channel.position;
        channelSilence.stop();
        channel.stop();
        channel2.stop();
        btnPlay.mouseEnabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: I want to be able to run the AS function "pauseMusic" from the javascript function returnVar3 when the HTML button is clicked.  Wheven I add the addCallback to AS I get an error

Comment: Can u able to paste `pauseMusic` and `song4` functions?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  It should be the song3 function.  I just want to be able to click the HTML and run AS3 code.  I might be doing this wrong.

Comment: What is that `evt:MouseEvent`? U should remove that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about the extend of your app but you've got your addCallback function parameters mixed up..

See [the doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29), the first parameter is the name you want to expose the function as to javascript, the second is the actual internal AS3 function you want to trigger.

So the declaration should likely be something like:

ExternalInterface.addCallback("song4", pauseMusic);

(assuming that your function in the same scope as where you call addCallback)

That statement will create a "song4" method that you can call on your flash dom object

```
var fl = document.getElementById('myflashobject');
fl.song4()
```

After there's the issue that pauseMusic want a parameter (looks like you've made it a mouse event handler). You probably want to have a clean method that doesn't require a parameter like an internal as3 event param. Rewrite pauseMusic so it doesn't require it (you might need to create another method to handle the mouse event internally - like onPause(evt:MouseEvent), which then calls pauseMusic.

**Edit**: I don't know if a lot of people thought about doing that, but you can also totally use external interface to call firebug's console.log function to send messages to Firebug from flash (it's really helpful for debugging ExternalInterface issues, or any other flash problems - see the [ExternalInterface.call](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29) function)

Comment: Thanks Ben, that makes a lot of sense.  I'm still relatively new to this trying to learn as I go.  I switched the parameters around and now I'm getting the same error on export.  I have revised with my new pause/external code.  What parameter would I pass in if I only want this function to listen for javascript?

Comment: Is this happening because ExternalInterface is not inside of a function?

Comment: @user547794. I'm not sure, I don't really know the rest of your project. I'd recommend you do a test project with a simple external interface and try to get that to work - maybe something that outputs a string passed from JS onto a flash text field or something like that... Once that works, try to apply it to your bigger scale probject.

Answer (score 0):

Hope u want to pause the audio player.

AS code :

```
 ExternalInterface.addCallback("sndToAS",rcvdFmJS);
    function rcvdFmJS(val){
       if (val == "pause"){
      audioPause();
       }
    }
```

JS code :

```
    document.getElementById("movie").sndToAS("pause");
```